# Why are Anchor properties not being honored within dynamically created nested components?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

Let me begin by saying that I have not done a lot of Windows Forms development -- if there is an obvious mistake that I may be making, please don't hesitate to mention it.

Steps to reproduce my issue:

- Create a new C# Windows Forms Project using VS 2010 or VS 2012
- Using the VS Form Designer, add three FlowLayoutPanel components to the form
- Set each FlowLayoutPanel to have the same height as the form and approximately 1/3 the width of the form
- Position each FlowLayoutPanel so that they do not overlap each other horizontally and collectively consume approximately the entire area of the Form.
- The leftmost FlowLayoutPanel is configured to have an Anchor of Top, Bottom, Left
- The middle FlowLayoutPanel is configured to have an Anchor of Top, Bottom
- The rightmost FlowLayoutPanel is configured to have an Anchor of Top, Bottom, Right

Add an event for Form_Shown:

```
private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Panel p = new Panel();
  p.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
  p.Width = 200;
  p.Height = 100;

  Label label1 = new Label();
  label1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
  label1.Text = "Hello";
  label1.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top;

  Label label2 = new Label();
  label2.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
  label2.Text = "World!";
  label2.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom;

  p.Controls.Add(label1);
  p.Controls.Add(label2);

  middleFlow.Controls.Add(p); // add to the center most FlowLayoutPanel on Form1
}
```

The result seems to be that label1 is placed on top of label2, despite label2 being added second.  Moreover, the anchor values seem to be ignored (as label1 is covering label2 when I intend for them to be anchored to the top and bottom of the Panel component, respectively)

If I use the Dock property instead of the Anchor property, the behavior is as desired.  Why does the Anchor property not work in this situation?

Also, is there a way to anchor components to other components?  I notice as I increase the size of my Form at runtime, horizontal "gaps" between panels appear.  Ideally, I would like the panels to grow together, preventing any gaps/whitespace between them horizontally?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions or tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still starting to learn c# and winforms, so the following may not be optimal but it does what you required.

Handled the labels with Dock=Top. Note that the labels are switched so that label1 is on top of label2, i.e., registering label1 last pushes down the already registered label2.

The positioning of the three panels is done without anchors and docks with an event handler for resize. Setting the size of the form after that raises a resize event. Colored to see the components.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;


public class ThreePanel : Form {

  FlowLayoutPanel  leftFlow;
  FlowLayoutPanel  middleFlow;
  FlowLayoutPanel  rightFlow;

  public ThreePanel(){


    leftFlow = new FlowLayoutPanel() {
      BackColor = Color.Yellow
    };

    middleFlow = new FlowLayoutPanel() {
      BackColor = Color.LightGreen
    };

    rightFlow = new FlowLayoutPanel() {
      BackColor = Color.LightBlue
    };

    this.Controls.Add(rightFlow);
    this.Controls.Add(middleFlow);
    this.Controls.Add(leftFlow);

    this.Load += (s,e)=>Form1_Shown(s,e);
    this.Resize += (s,e)=>{ 
      int w=this.Width/3; 
      leftFlow.Width=middleFlow.Width
          =rightFlow.Width=w;
      leftFlow.Height=middleFlow.Height
          =rightFlow.Height=this.Height;
      leftFlow.Location=new Point(0,0);
      middleFlow.Location=new Point(w,0);
      rightFlow.Location=new Point(2*w,0);
    };

    this.Size = new Size(750,450);

  }

  private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    Panel p = new Panel() {
      BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle,
      Width = 200,
      Height = 100,
      BackColor = Color.Fuchsia,
    };

    Label label1 = new Label() {
      BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle,
      Text = "Hello",
      Dock = DockStyle.Top
    };

    Label label2 = new Label() {
      BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle,
      Text = "World!",
      Dock = DockStyle.Top
    };

    p.Controls.Add(label2);
    p.Controls.Add(label1);

    // add to the center most FlowLayoutPanel on Form1
    middleFlow.Controls.Add(p); 
  }

  public static void Main()
  {
    Application.Run(new ThreePanel());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would expect exactly the behaviour that you mentioned.

The Anchor property only tells the parent container that the label should be sticked
to the parent. In your case AnchorStyles.Top means stick the label to the top and leave it there if the parent moves or resizes.

You did not specify dimensions or positions for the labels, so both overlapp.
The z-order of the controls is created implicitly from the order when added to middleFlow.Controls. You can check this using VS forms designer. Select "Bring to Front" or "Send to Back" and watch how the x.designer.cs changes.
Why it is in reverse order is one of the little .net secrets. The workaround is to change the order. Sometimes it is easier to do it manually than in the designer.